# How many Short Rests does the average table take?

Tags: dnd-5e, rests

Simply put, are there statistics on how many Short Rests most tables take per Long Rest?

Perhaps as something researched by WotC or another entity?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104981/discussion-on-question-by-daniel-zastoupil-how-many-short-rests-does-the-average).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Two to Three rests before a Long Rest

In my current game, been playing for 2 years, we take 2 to three rest between Long Rests if we have some form of fighting encounters. But sometimes we might not even take a short rest if we are doing well and combat goes fast.

It can also be seen in this [pool](https://www.enworld.org/threads/how-often-does-your-party-take-a-short-rest.652607/) that of all 83 votes that two short rest per long rest are the most voted. Jeremy also [said](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2016/01/21/how-many-short-rests-characters-can-take-per-day/) that the limit of short rest is only limited to how many hours in the day and monster interruption, so it depends on how many "hard" encounters you get and if you are feeling weak.

But we have to remember that not taking short rest is "bad" since the game was balanced around the idea of taking short rests between encounters, that shows when well when you have a Warlock in your party and those spells slots refresh.

Comment: While I appreciate the effort, 83 votes out of tens of thousands of D&D gaming tables is hardly a way to get an average, wouldn't you agree?

Comment: You mention that you have 2-3 Short Rests if you have **a** combat encounter.  Was there reason to take the additional short rests after?

Comment: Yes, I had to regain one of my Subclass abilities, so we took a short rest so I could use it again.